# The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable. Not doing distinct operation

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

In SQL Server table, one of the columne "question" has data type as "text".

Now, when i make query in sql then, use casting to varchar.

Now, in linq following is the query where retrieving specific result data.

The problem is, it gives me below error when i try to iterate result set in `FOR` OR `FOREACH` loop. I googled but, it says , that happen when do distinct but, i am not doing distinct operation.

`The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable`

```
from t in db.Table
group t by new 
          {
           t.Category, 
           t.Question
          } into g
order by g.Category
select new 
{
  CategoryName = t.FirstOrDefault().Category, //might be required to handle null here
  Question = t.FirstOrDefault().Question, //might be required to handle null here
  TotalCount = t.Count(),
  AnsLessEqual3 = t.Where(d => d.Answer<=3).Count(),
  Ans5 = t.Where(d => d.Answer = 5).Count(),
  Ans789 = t.Where(d => d.Answer = 7 || d.Answer = 8 || d.Answer =     9).Count()
 }
```

Please guide how to fix this.

Comment: GROUP BY works like DISTINCT.  I'm assuming one of your `group` expressions is a TEXT data type - `Question` would make the most sense.  Is there a non-text field (question id?) that you can group on instead?

Comment: yes, "question" is the field in group by clause as well as select clause.

Comment: Then I would rearrange your query so that you're not grouping by a text field.

Comment: can you please do that. i need same result which can be get through above query.

Comment: I know exactly nothing about linq, do you you a select statement somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to get LINQ to convert your text field to a varchar, grabbing the entire Substring should do the trick.  Also, you should stick within your group, otherwise you will be summarizing the entire table, assuming LINQ would allow it.

```
from t in db.Table
group t by new 
          {
           Category = t.Category.Substring(0), 
           t.Question
          } into g
orderby g.Key.Category
select new 
{
    CategoryName = g.Key.Category,
    Question = g.Key.Question,
    TotalCount = g.Count(),
    AnsLessEqual3 = g.Count(d => d.Answer <= 3),
    Ans5 = g.Count(d => d.Answer = 5),
    Ans789 = g.Count(d => d.Answer = 7 || d.Answer = 8 || d.Answer = 9)
 }
```

Comment: How to convert text to string in linq.

Comment: How to convert text to string in linq. i mean, how can i apply substring to grab the data and make it string. if you can give example then, its helps.

Comment: Category = t.Category.Substring(0) within the group clause is what does the trick, the rest of my changes were cleanup. Have you had a chance to try it?

Answer (score -2):

The text datatype has been deprecated since 2005. You should not use it. It is a pain to work with. You should instead use varchar(max). I would recommend changing your table to varchar(max) instead.

Comment: ya,but now, it is not my hand. managed by client. i need to find some alternative here. this is existing database.

Comment: Of course the database exists. It is a simple alter statement to use varchar(max) instead of text. I have done it plenty of times and there is no data loss at all.

Comment: ya, its true. but, not in my hand as it is in client control. for now, i need to find solution in linq or `for` loop where getting this exception.